# How do I define a textview outside of the activity class?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-location

I have a location listener object, and I wanted to know how to define a TextView outside of the activity class. In `LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.main, null)` I get an unresolved reference for 'context' and 'main'. For
`val locTextView = MainActivity.findViewById(R.id.locTextView) as TextView1` I get an unresolved reference for findViewById.

```
private val locationListener: LocationListener = object : LocationListener {
    override fun onLocationChanged(location: Location) {
        val v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.main, null)
        val locTextView = MainActivity.findViewById(R.id.locTextView) as TextView
        locTextView.setText("" + location.longitude + ":" + location.latitude);
    }
    override fun onStatusChanged(provider: String, status: Int, extras: Bundle) {}
    override fun onProviderEnabled(provider: String) {}
    override fun onProviderDisabled(provider: String) {}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

change your this line

```
val v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.main, null)
```

with

```
val v = LayoutInflater.from(applicationContext).inflate(R.layout.main, null)
```

and again 
change your

```
MainActivity.findViewById(R.id.locTextView) as TextView
```

with

```
 val locTextView =  findViewById< TextView>(R.id.locTextView)
```

**UPDATE**

If you would like to use [Kotlin Android Extention](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html) , then say goodbye to `findViewById()`